# Read multiple files in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I use RMarkdown and would like to source multiple .R files before knitting the document. I split my .R files into "read.R" and "calc.R", but rmarkdown returns an error with this method. However if I combine read.R and calc.R into a single file ("combined.R") it runs with no problem.

Here's what I'd like to do.
Read this data in one .R file.

```
# Read.R
game <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
royals <- c(5,7,3,5,7)
mets <- c(4,1,9,3,2)
data <- data.frame(game,royals,mets)
```

Then calc in another .R file.

```
# Calc.R
data$winner <- ifelse(data$royals>data$mets,"royals","mets")
```

Then run rmarkdown. This doesn't work (sourcing separate files)...

````
---
title: "rmd_test"
author: "me"
date: "Monday, November 02, 2015"
output: word_document
---
```{r}
source("read.R")
source("calc.R")
print(data)
```
````

But sourcing a single combined file does...

```
# Combined.R
# Read data
game <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
royals <- c(5,7,3,5,7)
mets <- c(4,1,9,3,2)
data <- data.frame(game,royals,mets)
# Calc
data$winner <- ifelse(data$royals>data$mets,"royals","mets")
```

Here's the same rmarkdown file sourcing a single combined.R file.

````
---
title: "rmd_test"
author: "me"
date: "Monday, November 02, 2015"
output: word_document
---
```{r}
source("combined.R")
print(data)
```
````

I would like to split the files because my "read.R" files are fairly generic and stable, but the "calc.R" changes and is variable. So it is more convenient to split the two.

Comment: You source `data.R`, but your Rscipt's name is `read.R`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That wasn't an issue with my other files but by I changed the rmd file so that I source all files in every chunk and that solves the problem. Figured it was something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code between different scripts or even projects. You should consider to put this in a separate package. While this is truly more effort at the beginning, this might pay off later, when your projects are growing or you want to share your code with others.
If you are a "R-package" newbie (like me), there is a very good book by Hadley Wickham available online: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/